# Convert Multidimensional Array Into Individual Strings in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to take a multidimensional array:

```
m_array = [["S39.91", "S39.91"], ["B99.9"]]
```

And convert it to individual strings based on its grouping:

```
String One = "S39.91, S39.91"
String Two = "B99.9"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about:

`m_array.map { |strings| strings.join(', ') }`

That will give you an array:

`["S39.91, S39.91", "B99.9"]`

Which you can then use to assign to variables:

```
string_1, string_2 = ["S39.91, S39.91", "B99.9"]
```

Comment: Great. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Nice, but consider consolidating your code into one line, i.e. `string1, string2 = m_array.map { |arr| arr.join(', ') }`

Comment: @sagarpandya82 : No. First line works with any length, second line is for the special case of an array with two elements.

Comment: @EricDuminil I don't understand what you're are saying. The first line creates a new array, the second line assigns the variables. My suggestion is to do both in one line.

Comment: I'm just saying that we don't know if the array only has 2 elements, or more.

Comment: @EricDuminil `m_array.size` will be the same as `m_array.map {...}.size.` so it doesn't matter when you do the parallel assignment.

Comment: @sagarpandya82 exactly. We can combine it into a single line but we're not playing golf. This is just a way to break it down so the OP can adapt it to their use.

Comment: @EricDuminil how about this then `string1, string2, *rest = m_array.map { |arr| arr.join(', ') }` :)